Sources for Curses for Rune Weapons in Palladium / Rifts?
In Palladium's flagship line Rifts there are magical weapons called Rune Weapons.  Rune weapons while immensely powerful often tend to be cursed.
I've developed a rune weapon in Rifts for a player character I will be adding into an existing campaign.  The weapon is an orb which contains the essence/soul of Sol Invictus.  The problem that I am encountering is building workable curse into the rune weapon.
Has anyone found a good source of curses Palladium, Rifts, or other for magic weapon curses (they need not be rune weapon specific)?
